# coffee-script is not installing on amazon ec2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm, coffeescript

I am using mac terminal to access my amazon ec2 free tier. I installed node and npm using commands.

but when I tried to install Coffee-Script using below command, it gives error and warnings. I don't know what to do. Please help me.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx /]$ npm install -g coffee-script


npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/lib
└── coffee-script@1.10.0 

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "coffee-script"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "coffee-script"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.3173130556
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.3173130556'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.3173130556'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.3173130556' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
```

Also I tried :

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx /]$ sudo npm install -g coffee-script
sudo: npm: command not found
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NPM installation is in a privileged space forcing you to use `sudo` to make any changes. The problem, is that you're PATH isn't being passed to the sudo'd shell.

You can modify the sudoers PATH by editing the `secure_path` field in `/etc/sudoers`.

If you just want to get it installed, provide the full path to npm.

```sh
sudo $(which npm) install -g coffee-script
```